# Missing icons in Safari Favorites tab (OS X Yosemite)

Tags: safari, icon, bookmarks

Some of the bookmarks in my Favorites screen are consistently defaulting to an ugly gray icon even though they do have icons elsewhere. I don't know what to do about this. For example, here's what my favorite screen looks like:

[image: Favorites in tab view]

As you can see, there are proper icons coming up for the first two bookmarks (Stack Exchange and Facebook). But the remaining 3 are defaulting to the grayish pseudo-safari icons.

On the other hand, when I view my favorites in the edit mode, this is how they look:

[image: Favorites list in edit mode]

At least in one example, you can see the bookmark titled "Alliance Login" does seem to have an icon in this view. And yet it refuses to show up in the main tab. What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having this same issue. Try deleting the Library/Safari/Touch Icons/ folder

After that, relaunch Safari and it should download them all again. This worked for most of my icons with the exception of the websites that don't have any custom icons available.

Comment: This worked, except for almost all websites. However, YouTube still remains elusive and it's hard to believe a major website such as that would be lacking on something as basic as a browser icon! Is it just me or does YouTube really not show as a custom icon on anyone's safari?